# Impose an order for the prerequisites of a target

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu-make, target, prerequisites

I have a makefile snippet:

```
all: $(objects)
fresh: clean all
clean: ;rm $(objects)
```

Here, I want to ensure that when I do `make fresh` - `clean` should precede `all`.

But how can I make sure this, given that when I do `make all`, `clean` should not be made?

---

I can imagine that one way could be like this

```
fresh: clean
    make all
```

Is it the right (or the only) way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GNU make:

```
all:
    @echo $@
    @sleep 1
    @echo end $@

clean:
    @echo $@
    @sleep 1
    @echo end $@

fresh:: clean
fresh:: all

.PHONY: clean fresh all
```

Please note the double colon after target*s* `fresh`! See the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon):

> The double-colon rules for a target are executed in the order they
>   appear in the makefile.

If you run `make -j2 fresh` it shows it works as expect:

```
clean
end clean
all
end all
```

But with `fresh:: clean all` doesn't work properly parallel (maybe unexpected).

With BSD make:

```
 all:
    @echo $@
    @sleep 1
    @echo end $@

clean:
    @echo $@
    @sleep 1
    @echo end $@

fresh:  clean all
    @echo $@

.ORDER: clean all
.PHONY: clean all fresh
```

Note the line begin with `.ORDER`. It works well in parallelization too (see [man make](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html)). Without parallelization the order of dependencies in line `fresh:` counts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it also work when fresh depends on `clean` and `all`; and both are `Order only dependency`? I have a use case for this. What I meant is that first `clean` and then `all` should be made but both should be ordered only.

Comment: Alternatively. could you also also have a look at this : [makefile - Impose an order for Order-only-prerequisites of a target - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053988/impose-an-order-for-order-only-prerequisites-of-a-target)

Answer (score 1):

As you already suggest in your question, calling `make` *recursively* on the same makefile for the target `all` in a recipe whose prerequisite is `clean`:

```
# At the very beginning of the makefile
CURRENT_MAKEFILE :=  $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
# ...

.PHONY: fresh
fresh: clean
    $(MAKE) -f $(CURRENT_MAKEFILE) all
```

This imposes an order, since the target `fresh` depends on the prerequisite `clean`, `clean`'s recipe will be executed before `fresh`'s recipe, which in turn will execute `all`'s recipe.

Note that I'm using here [`$(MAKE)` instead of `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html) for the recursion.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. If the `fresh` target is matched, `clean` is a *phony target* (it should be made a phony target), and it is a prerequisite of `fresh` (as above), then `clean`'s recipe will run before `fresh`'s recipe, since `clean` will always be *out-of-date* (because it is a phony target).

Comment: Alternatively. could you also also have a look at this : [makefile - Impose an order for Order-only-prerequisites of a target - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053988/impose-an-order-for-order-only-prerequisites-of-a-target)