# Impose an order for Order-only-prerequisites of a target

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu-make, target, prerequisites

I have a makefile snippet:

```
all: $(objects) 
fresh: all | clean directory
directory: ;mkdir -p OutputDirectory
clean: ;rm $(objects); rm -rf OutputDirectory
```

Here, I want to ensure that when I do `make fresh` - `clean` should succeed by `directory` which should be followed by `all`.

Semantically, here it might not make sense for `clean` to be order only prerequisite. Assume it to some `order only dependency` that has to be executed in some order.

---

The following link shows similar problem but for normal dependencies: 
[makefile - Impose an order for the prerequisites of a target - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036534/impose-an-order-for-the-prerequisites-of-a-target/52043675#52043675)

Answer (score 2):

In `fresh`'s recipe, you could call `make` twice *recursively* on the same makefile, for the target that creates the directory and the `all` target, respectively:

```
# At the very beginning of the makefile
CURRENT_MAKEFILE :=  $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
# ...

.PHONY: all clean fresh

directory := OutputDirectory

all: $(objects) 
fresh: clean
    $(MAKE) -f $(CURRENT_MAKEFILE) $(directory)
    $(MAKE) -f $(CURRENT_MAKEFILE) all

$(directory): ;mkdir -p $@
clean: ;rm -f $(objects); rm -rf $(directory)
```

This way, the target `all` is preceded by the target `$(directory)`, which is in turn preceded by `clean`.

Comment: Hi! IMHO this is not `Order only dependency` as after the first run, OutputDirectory exists, but it is created again as the time stamp of the directory changes when new files are created inside it. Refer: Order only prerequisites from GNU Make documentation.

Comment: It was created again because `directory` was a *phony* target. If the target is however called `OutputDirectory` (i.e., the expansion of `$(directory)`), which corresponds to the directory you want to create, then, once it is created, and as long as it exists, `$(directory)`'s recipe won't be executed again.

Comment: Refer the last example at [GNU make: Prerequisite Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)

Comment: @Nikhil `$(directory)` above is not an*order-only prerequisite*, but IMHO it is not relevant. If `fresh` is matched, then its recipe is always executed, since it is a *phony* target. The `$(directory)`'s recipe is only going to be run if the directory does not exist, since `$(directory)` target has no prerequisites. I think that the net effect is the same in this case.